# Social media ‘@‘ dynamic dropdown and links

Tags: javascript, typescript, social-networking

I’m curious to know if the ‘@‘ linking that you see in several social media sites to reference another user (dropdown pops open, user is selected, text becomes a link) has a well defined pattern or solution that exists in the wild. I haven’t attempted to solve the problem myself because there is no need to reinvent the wheel if this sort of thing is laid out somewhere, and this problem is indeed several smaller problems in itself.

Everything I could think to search for hasn’t yielded any remotely close results.

Note: I would be implementing this is Typescript/javascript

Comment: I'm more than sure that there is no defined pattern and most of the devs created it their own way. You can still structure it by using `AJAX` live filtering/searching. I believe it is like your typical autocomplete just in a different context.

Comment: Look at [`this`](https://github.com/mopo922/jquery-mentionable) GitHub link for a `jQuery Plugin` called `Mentionable`. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Here is another link called [`Select2-mentions`](https://github.com/kylegibson/select2-mentions) which is a legacy `jQuery` plugin.